# Frequency of timing belt change on Volkswagen Golf

Tags: golf, timing-belt

What is the frequency to change the timing belt on a 2007 Volkswagen Golf 1.4 petrol ?

Reading https://www.gates.com/~/media/files/gates/automotive/catalogs/automotive/timingbeltreplacementguide.pdf?la=en it's every 6 years or the 'recommended interval' but what is the recommended interval for this model of Golf ? Does 6 years interval also apply to this Golf model ?

Update :

I bought the car in Ireland so is European region.
There is 150'000 km currently on clock. The belt has been changed once but I'm not sure at what interval. Based on these details belt should be changed approx every 90'000 km (likely miles not km) ?

Answer (score 1):

This information is located in the owner's manual. I do not have one of those, so I had to try to find the information online. Here is what I found.

I was not able to find a 1.4 liter engine for any of the 2007 VW Golf or GTi models. On page 62 (68) of the PDF you linked, all 2007 VW GTi/Golf have 2.0 liter engines and recommends the belt be changed at 90K (likely miles, not kilometers).

According to the [Bentley Publishers](https://wiki.bentleypublishers.com/display/tech/Maintenance+Schedule+-+2007+-+Jetta%2C+Rabbit%2C+GTI) the Golf and GTi engine should replace the timing belt at either 80,000 miles (128,000 kilometers) or 120,000 miles (180,000 kilometers), depending on engine model. If you in fact have the 2.0 liter engine, then it should be changed at 120,000 miles (180,000 kilometers).

You will need to verify your information first, relative to what region of the world you live in.

Comment: please see update

Comment: I still can't find a 1.4 liter in Europe for 2007 models. Look for your engine code and share it with us. Here is a video how to find it - [Where to find your VW chassis, engine or paint number](https://youtu.be/qj7x_1SPMxY). Tell us what that code is and we can verify what engine you have.

Comment: the engine code is BCA , does this help ?

Comment: On the chart I found, that is an engine code for 2006 1.4 liter engine. Must be an early 2007 model that got a 2006 code. Anyway, I am still struggling to find the information you are looking for.

Comment: Found this http://aam-europe.contitech.de/pages/downloads/docs/Poster-Wechselintervalle_de_en_es.pdf and BCA is15th row from column but I cannot interpret.

Comment: I saw that one too and had the same problem. By the icons at the top of the table, it leads me to believe it requires inspection, but does not indicate it *must* be replaced.

Comment: I just noticed intervals at bottom of that chart, the interval is missing for BCA, not sure why is missing  for this particular model.